# How to code predicates regarding lists in prolog family tree?

Tags: prolog

For a basic prolog program we are to define the following predicates:
Already defined predicates (an attempt)

a) `ancestor(X,Y)`, meaning that `X` is an ancestor of `Y`, i.e. either `X` is a parent
of `Y` or `X` is an ancestor of someone who is a parent of `Y`;

b) common `ancestor(X,Y,Z)`, meaning that `X` is a common ancestor of `Y`
and `Z`, i.e. `X` is an ancestor of both `Y` and `Z`;

c) closest common `ancestor(X,Y,Z)`, meaning that `X` is a closest common
ancestor of `Y` and `Z`, i.e. `X` is a common ancestor of `Y` and `Z` and no child
of `X` is a common ancestor of `Y` and `Z`;

---

Predicates **not** defined:

1) `ancestorList(X,Y,L)`, which holds iff `X` is an ancestor of `Y` and `L` is
a list of the decendants of `X` (i.e., people whose ancestor is `X`) that are ancestors
of `Y` ordered from the closest to the farthest from `X`; e.g. if john is
a parent of `paul` who is a parent of `henry` who is a parent of `helen`, then
`ancestorList(john,helen,L)` should succeed with `L = [paul,henry]`
being returned;

2) `descendantTree(X,L)`, which holds iff `L` is a list structure representing
the tree of all descendants of `X`; each node in the tree of descendants should be
represented by a list whose first element is the node label and the remaining elements are the representations of its children if any; e.g. if john’s children are `paul` and `mary`, `paul`’s children are `henry` and `june`, `henry`’s only child
is `helen`, `mary`’s only child is `adam`, and neither `adam` nor `june` nor `helen`
have any children, then `descendantTree(john,L)` should succeed with

```
    L =
      [john,
        [paul,
           [henry,
              [helen]
             ],
             [june]
          ],
          [mary,
            [adam]
          ]
        ]
```

being returned (indentations and line breaks have been added here for readability,
but your program should not do this).

I am just a little confused on how to start the defined predicates. Here is a list of the predicates I currently have:

```
child(X,Y) :- parent(Y,X).
not(P):- call(P), !, fail.
not(P).

ancestor(X,Y):- parent(X,Y).
ancestor(X,Y):- parent(Z,Y), ancestor(X,Z).

common_ancestor(X,Y,Z):- ancestor(X,Y), ancestor(X,Z).

closest_common_ancestor(X,Y,Z):-
    common_ancestor(X,Y,Z),
    \+(child(P,X),common_ancestor(P,Y,Z)).
ancestorList(X,Y,L):- ancestor(X,Y),
```

Is there anywhere I can refer to help me with this prolog predicates?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you missed the last part of question 2. Also, `\+ foo` is how you write `not(foo)` in Prolog; remove your `not/1` since it's only going to get you into trouble. And your nesting in `common_ancestor(child(P,X),Y)` etc. is almost certainly not what you want to do since Prolog will not "evaluate" the inner `child(P,X)` as Prolog predicates do not "return" this way. For ancestorList you probably need to repeat the kind of work you're doing in `ancestor` since only by recursively calling `parent/2` can you obtain the intermediate ancestors.

Comment: @DanielLyons Thank you for your feedback! I have added the rest of #2  You mentioned that prolog will not evaluate the inner nesting, how can I go about defining the remaining predicate of closest_common_ancestor  for "no child of X is a common ancestor of Y and Z"?

Comment: When you call some predicate like `child(P,X)`, either Prolog succeeds (possibly unifying P and X with some values) or it fails, in which case it will backtrack to begin searching for the next solution. So you would probably move the inner expression out and separate it with commas, like `\+ (child(P, X), common_ancestor(P, Y))`. But since you define `common_ancestor/3` and are calling it with two arguments here, this is not likely to work. The number of arguments (arity) is as important as the name in finding a Prolog predicate for execution.